# Replacing all column values using Window operation?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Hi Data frame  created like below.

```
df = sc.parallelize([
    (1, 3),
    (2, 3),
    (3, 2),
    (4,2),
    (1, 3)
]).toDF(["id",'t'])
```

it shows like below.

```
+---+---+
| id|  t|
+---+---+
|  1|  3|
|  2|  3|
|  3|  2|
|  4|  2|
|  1|  3|
+---+---+
```

my main aim  is ,I want to replace repeated value in every column with how many times repeated.

so i have tried flowing code it is not working as expected.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
column_list = ["id",'t']
w = Window.partitionBy(column_list)
dfmax=df.select(*((count(col(c)).over(w)).alias(c) for c in df.columns))
dfmax.show()
+---+---+
| id|  t|
+---+---+
|  2|  2|
|  2|  2|
|  1|  1|
|  1|  1|
|  1|  1|
+---+---+
```

my expected output will be

```
+---+---+
| id|  t|
+---+---+
|  2|  3|
|  1|  3|
|  1|  1|
|  1|  1|
|  2|  3|
+---+---+
```

Comment: I don't understand your expected output. Why are the `1`s there in the `t` column? Also, keep in mind that row order is not guaranteed to preserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you're looking for is simply:

```python
df.select(*[count(c).over(Window.partitionBy(c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).show()
#+---+---+
#| id|  t|
#+---+---+
#|  2|  3|
#|  2|  3|
#|  1|  2|
#|  1|  3|
#|  1|  2|
#+---+---+
```

The difference between this and what you posted is that we only partition by one column at a time.

Remember that DataFrames are unordered. If you wanted to maintain your row order, you could add an ordering column using `pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id()`:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id

df.withColumn("order", monotonically_increasing_id())\
    .select(*[count(c).over(Window.partitionBy(c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns])\
    .sort("order")\
    .drop("order")\
    .show()
#+---+---+
#| id|  t|
#+---+---+
#|  2|  3|
#|  1|  3|
#|  1|  2|
#|  1|  2|
#|  2|  3|
#+---+---+
```